# Is there a Mac to-do-list allowing a task-tree (task hierarchy)?

Tags: mac, software-rec, to-do

Is there a Mac to-do-list allowing a task-tree (task hierarchy)?  I just looked at "things" but found it only has "projects" and "tasks".

Any ideas what else can do the trick? (it also needs to have basic shortcuts)

Comment: I´m not sure whether you want to create a tree or just a linear sequence of tasks; anyway I guess you might want to check out OmniFocus http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus/ which has sequential tasks as an option.

Comment: Any other requirements or would OmniOutliner actually suffice?

Comment: Consider accepting one of the answers, or adding additional requirements that aren't satisfied by any of these programs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[TaskCoach](http://www.taskcoach.org/) will do what you're looking for, and there is a Mac version available.

Comment: Thanks afrazier.  Do you have experience with it?  I wonder if it is better then the software I currently use on windows (todolist)

Comment: [AbstractSpoon's ToDoList](http://www.codeproject.com/tools/ToDoList2.asp)?  I don't really have deep experience with either one, so I can't really comment on whether one is "better" than another.  What I think you'll find is that they're comparable but different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, because I don't use it myself, but I think [The Hit List](http://www.potionfactory.com/thehitlist/) supports subtasks. It's mentioned in [this article](http://cinnamonthoughts.org/2009/04/12/comparing-mac-task-managers-and-choosing-the-hit-list/) which compares some Mac task list programs.

Comment: It does — [screenshot of the *Learn The Hit List* example todo list](http://i.imgur.com/aUnb3.png).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you require but maybe you should look at [Tree](http://www.topoftree.jp/en/tree/). Its an outliner that allows you to view the outline vertically or horizontally. I used it occasionally in the past. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

[SlingPlan](http://www.slingplan.com) is a product of ours that may help with what you're looking for, we created the product.

> Every screen, feature, and function within SlingPlan emerged from our
>   customers "Wouldn't it be nice" list. On each page within SlingPlan
>   exists two important icons:  a direct link to the pages help video,
>   and  a support and suggestion feature to let us know how to adapt
>   SlingPlan.COM to your needs.  This is your tool, and it should do what
>   you need, no matter how big or how small.

Comment: Instead of marketing copy (a.k.a. fluff), it'd be more helpful/appropriate if you posted a screenshot or described the tree list feature (I can't really tell that there is one from the website).